# Password leak from PHP PDO object in error log

Tags: php, security, pdo, centos

When error occurs while creating PDO connection (using wrong driver like `sqlsrv` instead of `dblib` I get error in `/var/log/httpd/error_log` (CentOS) with my plaintext database password and username in it:

```
[error] [client 10.10.103.16] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in /var/www/html/index.php:1\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/index.php(1): PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=O...', 'plainTextUserOMG!', 'plainTextPasswordOMG!')\n#1 {main}
```

How to cover this this data to still log error but not leak it into log file?

Comment: @onetrickpony Password and user are both in variable. `new PDO("mssql:host=xxxx;dbname=xxxx", $variable, $variable);`

Comment: @David oh yeah? So how to store that password than?

Comment: @David could you point me out some more material to read about it?

Comment: @David you may be wrong. DBMS expects plain text password. If you hash the db password on the client, this logically becomesthe db password, as said in the link you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the calls in `try{..} catch(){...}` blocks to handle the exception manually. Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Answer (score -1):

PDO is capable to read the password from a file. See Example #2 or #3 here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

However, database access should not be allowed from external network.

In other contexts where you absolutely need to pass credentials to your own PHP functions as parameters, consider that object and array parameters aren't revealed in log messages / backtraces, so, for example a call to `login([$username, $password]);` (note the array syntax) in case of error will be logged a `a(Array)`

Comment: The question is about password, not DSN

Comment: DSN in a file may contain password, see the example linked